# mybatis get class name of insert parameter

Tags: insert, mybatis, classname

Is it possible to extract the class name of a parameter in an insert statement? Mybatis comes up with "there is no getter/setter for property class ..." 
Here is what I tried out

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="package.className">
insert into TABLE 
(ID,CLASS_NAME)
values
(#{id},#{property.class.name}
</insert>
```

Comment: You could try a custom type handler... `#{property,typeHandler=bla.MyTypeHandler}`

Comment: perfekt! works pretty good

Answer (score 0):

Try the experiment.

Java -

```
public class Test {
    private String id;
    private PropertyClass  property;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public PropertyClass getProperty() {
        return property;
    }
    public void setProperty(PropertyClass property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
    public String getPropertyClassName(){
        return this.property.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

Mybatis -

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="package.className">
    insert into TABLE 
        (ID,CLASS_NAME)
    values
        (#{id},#{propertyClassName}
</insert>
```

AND I find Mybatis source.

org.apache.ibatis.reflection.Reflector - 445 Line

```
public boolean hasGetter(String propertyName) {
    return getMethods.keySet().contains(propertyName);
}
```

Here connect the Property. 
 ex ) #{propertyClassName}

But there getMethods not have undeclared  methods 
 ex ) getClass(), notify() .... etc

Comment: Thanks - this should work but I'm not able to modify the source classes.